# Служба IKEEXT отключается после перезагрузки

Tags: windows, service

После перезагрузки Windows 10 служба оказывается отключена служба IKEEXT (Модули ключей IPsec для обмена ключами в интернете и протокола IP с проверкой подлинности) - независимо от того, в каком состоянии она была - запущена, остановлена, автоматический или ручной запуск.
Вручную ее удается без проблем включить и запустить.
Почему может изменяться состояние при перезагрузке?

Answer (score 0):

Виноват был старый S-Tera клиент для windows. Недавно, наконец, это исправили.